# Error en phpmyadmin command denied to user

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, web

estoy intentando hacer un "INSERT" a una tabla en **phpmyadmin**, pero me salta este mensaje de error:
***1142 - INSERT command denied to user 'pma'@'localhost' for table 'pma_userconfig'***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe que ocurre? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Pues tiene toda la pinta de ser un problema de permisos. Prueba accediendo como `root`:

```
mysql -u root
```

Y ejecutando:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'pma'@'localhost';
```

Si eso te funciona, define permisos más específicos.

Comment: ya lo he solucionado, la solución era extremadamente sencilla, solo había que pulsar en el botón que esta al lado de la _casa_, en la parte izquierda de arriba.